# How do i varying high voltage(80-100v) control using Arduino, PWM and Mosfet?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm

How can I control(Varying) high voltage (80-100v) using PWM and MOSFET? Basically, I want to control the LED light's brightness using Arduino which generates the PWM signal and control MOSFET.

Comment: Sense voltage feedback with loop attenuation, Kp  and perhaps phase lead compensation , Kd then control error with PWM with your PSU. What current  and input V?

Comment: get an LED driver that has a dimming feature